# How to remove the overlapping of circles in d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection, force-layout

I was trying to create a network graph using d3.js

While I increase the radius of circles it overlapped. How to avoid these overlapping.

I tried using collide function but it didn't worked out as expected

```
    force.nodes(json.nodes).links(links).charge(-500)
        .linkDistance(function (d) {
            if (d.target.bublesize == 12) {
                return 80;
            } else if (d.target.bublesize == 18) {
                return 90;
            } else {
                return link_distance;
            }
        }).collide(.5)

   force.start();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2NJ25/24/), and screenshot, with visible overlapping:

[image]

Comment: The force layout doesn't allow you to do that -- you have to ensure that nothing overlaps yourself.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff How can I do that. Did you mean to reduce the size of the circle or increase the link distance?

Comment: Both can help in this case. If you really want to do collision detection/prevention however, you have to implement that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Did you see

[Collision Detection example by Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)

it works also with the latest version of d3.js ...